# Add Two Numbers using Linked List printSum() not working

Tags: java

I am trying to write a main to print the result of adding two numbers from a class I created called ListNode. I tried to create a main and was getting errors. I have created objects and I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I would like to display the result. I am getting infinite loop error still.

```
package LinkedList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;

public class ListNode{

int value;
ListNode next; 

ListNode(){};
ListNode(int value){
    
    this.value = value;
}
ListNode(int value, ListNode next){
    
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public static ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    
    ListNode dummy_head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode list1 = l1;
    ListNode list2 = l2;
    ListNode result = dummy_head; 
    int carry = 0; 
    
    while(list1 != null || list2 != null) {
        
        int x = 0; 
        int y = 0; 
        int sum = x + y + carry;
        
        if(list1 != null) {
            
            x = list1.value;
        }
        else {
            
            x = 0;
        }
        if(list2 != null) {
            
            y = list2.value;
        }
        else {
            
            y = 0;
        }
        
        carry = sum / 10;
        result.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        result = result.next;
        if(list1 != null) {
            
            list1 = list1.next;
        }
        if(list2 != null) {
            
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
    }
    if(carry > 0) {
        
        result.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    
    return dummy_head.next;
        
}

public static void printSum(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    
    ListNode result = ListNode.addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);
    
    while(result.next != null) {
        
        System.out.println(result.value);
    }
    
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    
    ListNode lst1 = new ListNode();
    lst1.value = 3;
    lst1.next = new ListNode();
    lst1.next.value = 2;
    lst1.next.next = new ListNode();
    lst1.next.next.value = 1;
    
    ListNode lst2 = new ListNode();
    lst2.value = 3;
    lst2.next = new ListNode();
    lst2.next.value = 2;
    lst2.next.next = new ListNode();
    lst2.next.next.value = 1;
    
    ListNode.printSum(lst1, lst2);
    
    
    
    
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Your `while` loop is not changing the `result` variable, so you will "trap" in the `while`loop once you enter it.

Comment: updated the question. how do get these values to print?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the algorithm you're trying to implement, however the following is my best guess:

```
package LinkedList;

public class ListNode {

    int value;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode() {};

    ListNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    ListNode(int value, ListNode next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummy_head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode list1 = l1;
        ListNode list2 = l2;
        ListNode result = dummy_head;
        int carry = 0;

        while (list1 != null || list2 != null) {

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            if (list1 != null)
                x = list1.value;

            if (list2 != null)
                y = list2.value;

            int sum = x + y + carry;
            carry = sum / 10;
            result.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            result = result.next;
            
            if (list1 != null)
                list1 = list1.next;
            
            if (list2 != null)
                list2 = list2.next;
        }

        if (carry > 0)
            result.next = new ListNode(carry);

        return dummy_head.next;

    }

    public static void printSum(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode result = ListNode.addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);
        while (result != null) {
            System.out.println(result.value);
            result = result.next;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ListNode lst1 = new ListNode();
        lst1.value = 3;
        lst1.next = new ListNode();
        lst1.next.value = 2;
        lst1.next.next = new ListNode();
        lst1.next.next.value = 1;

        ListNode lst2 = new ListNode();
        lst2.value = 3;
        lst2.next = new ListNode();
        lst2.next.value = 2;
        lst2.next.next = new ListNode();
        lst2.next.next.value = 1;

        ListNode.printSum(lst1, lst2);

    }

}
```

Some considerations:

1. Please format and indent better your code, it really helps **you** to read it better
2. You create and assign x and y on every iteration. This let you assume that the initial value for them is *always* 0 on each iteration, so no need for the `else` statements.
3. You are computing sum before compute x and y, so they will always be zero (I moved that instruction some lines down)
4. In the `printSum()` iteration you are never advancing from the initial `result` element, so the cycle will never end (I fixed that).

Comment: Check out Add Two Numbers LeetCode, I am basically just trying to write a main method to run it. Nothing crazy